# Python input and random system

Tags: python, random, input

I'm making an input system that asks for the user if the user selects low or high and then prints out if it's low or high with:

```
print(random.randint(1, 2))
```

But it gives this error:

```
  File "main.py", line 13
    print(random.randint(1, 2))
                              ^
```

IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

**pls debug me here's the code**

```
import random
print("Hello Welcome to the up down game!")

while True:

  first = input("[1]Low or [2]High. Which one?\n")


 print(random.randint(1, 2))
break
```

Comment: Indentation of `print(random.randint(1, 2))` is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

in python you should be careful on `Indentation`, see code below: (see this [ref](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/indentation.html))

```
import random
print("Hello Welcome to the up down game!")
while True:
    first = input("[1]Low or [2]High. Which one?\n")
    print(random.randint(1, 2))
    break
```

Comment: i got this error Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 4, in <module>
    print(random.randint(1, 2))
NameError: name 'random' is not defined

Comment: `import random`

Comment: @nebula234 OP's code should replace your ```while``` loop. You need to import ```random``` using ```import random```

Comment: @nebula234, I edit code block, check you get error or not?

Comment: im sure i imported random

Answer (score -1):

You have indented your code wrong.

```py
import random
print("Hello Welcome to the up down game!")
while True:
    first = input("[1]Low or [2]High. Which one?\n")
    print(random.randint(1, 2))
    break
```

Try this and it will work !